# vmware conflicts with physical servers

Tags: vmware-esxi, synology

I'm running some HP Proliant DL360 G6 servers with vmware esxi, and I have a Synology Diskstation appliance, all connected to a layer3 switch "Cisco Catalyst 4500" in a specific vlan and every server has its own static ip address with no dhcp pools configured in this network.

The problem is that sometimes when I call the Diskstation ip address a vmware server, specifically the first server, responds although it has its own static ip and doesn't conflict with any other server.

Sometimes the Diskstation responds and it works.

What could the cause be? it first looked to me like an ip conflict or something cause of observed ip range in vmware, but still can't see how to solve this problem.

Comment: `The problem is that sometimes when I call the Diskstation ip address a vmware server "specifically the first server" responds although it has its own static ip and doesn't conflict with any other server. Sometimes the Diskstation responds and it works.` What are you trying to say here? What you've written doesn't make sense, so we can't really help you. Please re-write this section as an edit to your question.

Comment: I mean sometimes when I navigate to the Diskstation ip address in the browser it shows the vmware-esxi page and I can connect to the esxi server with the vsphere client although that ip address wasn't assigned to the esxi server !
Sorry my English is bad.

Comment: If that happens, then you *have* assigned the IP to a management interface on your server. Double check your config.

Comment: Just out of interest look at the binary version of the MAC address of both the NAS and server - I wonder if you may have a single-bit error in your switch's CAM table memory???

Answer (score 2):

You either have an IP conflict (likely) or a MAC address conflict.  There is no other reasonable way for this to occur.

If you really can't find the IP conflict, try sending out an arping to the target IP address using the `arping` utility for linux, or something like that.  Watch what comes back.  If you want you can even run wireshark and watch the traffic.

Chances are you forgot to change MAC addresses when cloning VMs, or assigned one IP address to many things.

Because you can intermittently connect to it with the vsphere client, as MDMarra says, chances are the conflict is between your diskstation and the management interface of your ESXi server.  Check this in the ESXi server's console; it is displayed on the default screen.